# CSS strikethrough different color from text?

Tags: html, css

The HTML elements `del`, `strike`, or `s` may all be used for a text strike-through effect. Examples:

```
<del>del</del>
```

....gives: <del>del</del>

```
<strike>strike</strike> and <s>strike</s>
```

....gives: <strike>strike</strike> and <s>strike</s>

The CSS `text-decoration` property with a value `line-through` may be used similarly. The code...

```
<span style='text-decoration:line-through'>
    text-decoration:line-through
</span>
```

...will also render to look like: <strike>text-decoration:line-through</strike>

However, the strikethrough line is typically the same color as the text.

Can CSS be used to make the line a different color?

Comment: For a transparent strike through effect, you can see [transparent strikethrought on text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082524/css-text-with-transparent-strikethrought)

Answer (score 460, accepted):

Yes, by adding an extra wrapping element. Assign the desired line-through color to an outer element, then the desired text color to the inner element. For example:

```html
<span style='color:red;text-decoration:line-through'>
  <span style='color:black'>black with red strikethrough</span>
</span>
```

...or...

```html
<strike style='color:red'>
  <span style='color:black'>black with red strikethrough<span>
</strike>
```

(Note, however, that `<strike>` is [considered deprecated in HTML4 and obsolete in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strike) ([see also W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#strike)). The recommended approach is to use `<del>` if a true meaning of deletion is intended, or otherwise to use an `<s>` element or style with `text-decoration` CSS as in the first example here.)

To make the strikethrough appear for a:hover, an explicit stylesheet (declared or referenced in `<HEAD>`) must be used. (The `:hover` pseudo-class can't be applied with inline STYLE attributes.) For example:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    a.redStrikeHover:hover {
      color:red;
      text-decoration:line-through;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href='#' class='redStrikeHover'>
    <span style='color:black'>hover me</span>
  </a>
</body>
```

(IE7 seems to require some `href` be set on the `<a>` before `:hover` has an effect; FF and WebKit-based browsers do not.)

Comment: So much for my "that's impossible!" answer.

Comment: Yes, in my tests in FF3+, IE7+, Chrome. See added section, above.

Comment: Jquery implementation would be very useful.

Comment: @utype Why would you use jQuery for this?

Comment: Wrapper elements kinda suck. In most cases you can achieve almost the same effect with simple pseudoelement, i.e. `del { position:relative }` and then `del::after { content:'', position:absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; right:0; border-bottom: 1px solid #f00 }`.

Comment: `<strike>` is deprecated, but `<del>` works just as well for this purpose.

Comment: Just a wrapper. Ingenious. Oh my god, that's better than everything I came up with (pseudo-elements). Great job!

Comment: The referenced source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strike  does not actually say `<s>` is deprecated; only that `<strike>` is.  In fact, both it and W3.org recommend to use `<s>` instead of `<strike>` (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html) ("Use del instead if the element is marking an edit, otherwise use s instead.")

Comment: @AaronWallentine Good point; I'll apply your earlier-suggested correction.

Comment: @gojmo LOL .. thanks. : ) It got rejected by the official "quorum of my SE peers"

Answer (score 81):

**As of Feb. 2016**, CSS 3 has the support mentioned below. Here is a snippet from a WooCommerce's single product page with price discount

```
/*Price before discount on single product page*/
body.single-product .price del .amount {
color:           hsl(0, 90%, 65%);
font-size:       15px;
text-decoration: line-through;
/*noinspection CssOverwrittenProperties*/
text-decoration: white double line-through; /* Ignored in CSS1/CSS2 UAs */
}
```

Resulting in:
[image: Text decoration example]

---

CSS 3 will likely have direct support using the [`text-decoration-color` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color). In particular:

> The `text-decoration-color` CSS property sets the color used when drawing underlines, overlines, or strike-throughs specified by `text-decoration-line`. This is the preferred way to color these text decorations, rather than using combinations of other HTML elements.

Also see [`text-decoration-color` in the CSS 3 draft spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-color).

If you want to use this method immediately, you probably have to prefix it, using `-moz-text-decoration-color`. (Also specify it without `-moz-`, for forward-compatibility.)

Comment: "CSS 3 will likely have" is rather... optimistic.

Comment: @BoltClock: How is it optimistic? It's already in the W3C working draft, which is being actively pursued.

Comment: According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration), no browsers are currently (in 2014) supporting `text-decoration-color` without prefixes.

Comment: And 3 years later...Firefox and Safari have it = 20% of reach.

Comment: according to the caniuse, currently is supported by FireFox only

Comment: Google Chrome 61 has it!

Comment: As of March 2019 `text-decoration-color` is supported by every major browser except for any Microsoft browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Note you have to separate out each style for it to work on iOS: text-decoration-color:red; text-decoration-style: solid; NOT one text-decoration style.

Answer (score 42):

I've used an empty `:after` element and decorated one border on it. You can even use CSS transforms to rotate it for a slanted line. [Result: pure CSS, no extra HTML elements!](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/zd174wb4/) Downside: doesn't wrap across multiple lines, although IMO you shouldn't use strikethrough on large blocks of text anyway.

```css
s,
strike {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*we're replacing the default line-through*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* keeps it from wrapping across multiple lines */
}

s:after,
strike:after {
  content: "";
  /* required property */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  height: 45%;
  /* adjust as necessary, depending on line thickness */
  /* or use calc() if you don't need to support IE8: */
  height: calc(50% - 1px);
  /* 1px = half the line thickness */
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotateZ(-4deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Here comes some <strike>strike-through</strike> text!</p>
```

Comment: @Veve [HTML strikethrough element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s) -- the non-semantic version

Comment: thanks, I looked for this, specially the rotate line

Comment: Using a :after method is likely to have issues with accessibility

Answer (score 16):

This CSS3 will make you line through property more easier, and working fine.

```
span{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you do not care about internet explorer\edge, then simplest way to achieve different color for strike-through would be to use CSS property: 
**text-decoration-color** in conjunction with text-decoration:line-through;

```
.yourClass {
    text-decoration: line-through !important;
    text-decoration-color: red !important;
}
```

-- Does not work with Edge\Internet Explorer

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @gojomo you could use `:after` pseudo element for the additional element. The only caveat is that you'll need to define your `innerText` in a `data-text` attribute since CSS has limited `content` functions.

```css
s {
  color: red;
  text-align: -1000em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
s:after {
  color: black;
  content: attr(data-text);
}
```

```html
<s data-text="Strikethrough">Strikethrough</s>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach which uses a gradient to fake the line. It works with multiline strikes and doesn't need additional DOM elements. But as it's a background gradient, it's behind the text...

```css
del, strike {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.63em, transparent), color-stop(0.63em, #ff0000), color-stop(0.7em, #ff0000), color-stop(0.7em, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0em, transparent 0.63em, #ff0000 0.63em, #ff0000 0.7em, transparent 0.7em, transparent 1.4em);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0em, transparent 0.63em, #ff0000 0.63em, #ff0000 0.7em, transparent 0.7em, transparent 1.4em);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0em, transparent 0.63em, #ff0000 0.63em, #ff0000 0.7em, transparent 0.7em, transparent 1.4em);
  -webkit-background-size: 1.4em 1.4em;
  background-size: 1.4em 1.4em;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YSvaY/

Gradient color-stops and background size depend on line-height. (I used LESS for calculation and Autoprefixer afterwards...)

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```html
<style>body {color: #000;}</style>
<del>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#999">facebook</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</del>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my experience the

```
<span style='color:red;text-decoration:line-through'>
    <span style='color:black'>black with red strikethrough</span>
</span>
```

isn't the best option. I had a co worker use this method without testing cross browser, so I had to go back and fix it because it caused issues in firefox. My personal recommendation would be to use the :after selector to create a strikethrough. That way it can go back to IE8 if you really wanted to without any style conflicts as well as solid across all other browsers.

It also creates less markup and about the same amount of styling which in my opinion is a pretty big deal.

So if anyone else runs into similar issues hopefully this can help out:

```
.lineThrough {
    position: relative;

   &:after {
      content: "  ";
      display: block;
      width: 60px;
      height: 1px;
      background: red;
      position: absolute;
      top: 49%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -30px;
   }
}
```

obviously you could use transform: translate instead of margins, but this example is to work back to IE8

Answer (score 4):

Single Property solution is:

```
.className {
    text-decoration: line-through red;
};
```

Define your color after line through property.

Answer (score 2):

Blazemonger's reply (above or below) needs voting up - but I don't have enough points.

I wanted to add a grey bar across some 20px wide CSS round buttons to indicate "not available" and tweaked Blazemonger's css:

```
.round_btn:after {
    content:"";    /* required property */
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: -1px;
    border-top: 6px solid rgba(170,170,170,0.65);
    height: 6px;
    width: 19px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an update, this can be easily done now by doing:

```
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration: underline dotted;
text-decoration: underline dotted red;
text-decoration: green wavy underline;
text-decoration: underline overline #FF3028;
```

then add the desired font color with color: ....

Adding something that wasn't obvious to me when you apply this to React inline styling:

```
<p style= {{textDecoration:'line-through red', color:'gray'}} >
```

you need to switch the '-' for cammel case.

This renders the content of

....

in color gray crossed out by a red line.

For more details check the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Answer (score 1):

If it helps someone you can just use css property

`text-decoration-color: red;`

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the desired line-through color to a parent element works for the deleted text element (`<del>`) as well - making the assumption the client renders `<del>` as a line-through.

http://jsfiddle.net/kpowz/vn9RC/

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by placing a span inside an  element and assigning each a distinct color.

```html
<s style="color: red;">
  <span style="color: black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</s>
```

Answer (score -5):

Here is a sample jQuery implementation – thanks to gojomo's answer and utype's suggestion (+1 for both)

```
$(function(){
  //===================================================================
  // Special price strike-out text
  // Usage:
  //   Normally:    <span class='price'>$59</span>
  //   On special:  <span class='price' special='$29'>$59</span>
  //===================================================================
  $(".price[special]").each(function() {
    var originalPrice = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<strike><span>' + originalPrice +'</span></strike> ' + $(this).attr('special'))
           .removeAttr('special')
           .addClass('special');
  });
});
```

The CSS for that could be

```
.price strike, .price.special { color: Red; }
.price strike span { color: Black; }
```

Comment: Which part is invalid? It worked on all major browsers though

Comment: "Works" and "valid" are quite far away from each other. Browsers try to interpret even HTML that has several errors in it. See [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/), [Why is valid HTML important to everyone?](http://rebuildingtheweb.com/en/why-is-valid-html-important/), [HTML valid DIV attributes? on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185519/html-valid-div-attributes)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, changing the attribute name to "data-special" should make it valid HTML5.

Comment: jQuery to add a wrapper to get a colored strike-through? What have we become?!

Comment: Seems like a possible XSS problem: you have plain text in `originalPrice`, then inject it back as HTML. Try using `.html()` instead of `.text()`. Or maybe use jQuery's `wrap()`.