# What are valid attributes for the DIV element in HTML?

Tags: html

What are all the valid `DIV` attributes?

Based on [this link](http://learningforlife.fsu.edu/webmaster/references/xhtml/tags/text/div.cfm), it appears only `class`, `id`, `title`. Is that correct? Meaning, the `for` attribute and others is not valid for `DIV`?

Comment: What would you expect `<div for="...">` to do?

Comment: @Lazarus - I think the best comment would be to educate JasonK on the proper place to find this information like Sinan Ünür has done. Rather than calling his question lazy. He may be new to web development and not actually know where to find the answer.

Comment: @Bryan, if you are happy to do what is simple, basic investigation using Google or similar, just like JasonK could have done, for him then go ahead. I will continue to be disappointed that people here continue to pander to the lazy, and it is lazy, it's clear he didn't try for more than 30 seconds to find the information before deciding to get someone here to do it for them. Sinan didn't educate him in how to find the information, he *gave* it to him. "Search using Google" is education in *how* to find the information.

Comment: @Lazarus - Sinan Ünür did educate him on how to find this information.

"See W3C specs:"

He was also helpful in providing the information in his answer rather than blindly linking to the W3C spec.

I'm sorry, but this site becomes useless when one answers with "Search using Google"...or refuses to answer at all when they know the information.

Comment: @Byran, I guess that depends on the value in the question and whether it's worth duplicating information that's available in dozens of other places. Particularly when it's not even a programming problem. Sinan also didn't just say "See W3C specs", but provided an extract and further information duplicating what's on the page provided in the link. This is a programming Q&A site, not a repository for all knowledge available on the internet.

Comment: @Lazarus This is the first search result from google, "non-lazy" people in the future searching for this will come here.

Comment: How come I cannot find <div key=.... >, the "key" as a attribute in the W3C ?  Thanks

Answer (score 38):

See [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4):

> - `id`, `class` (document-wide identifiers)
> - `lang` (language information), `dir` (text direction)
> - `title` (element title)
> - `style` (inline style information)
> - `align` (alignment)
> - `onclick`, `ondblclick`, `onmousedown`, `onmouseup`, `onmouseover`, `onmousemove`, `onmouseout`, `onkeypress`, `onkeydown`, `onkeyup`

`for` is for [`label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) and specifies the `id` attribute of the input element to which the label applies.

See also the [HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element):

> The `div` element has no special meaning at all. It represents its children. It can be used with the `class`, `lang`, and `title` attributes to mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements.
>
> > **Note:** Authors are strongly encouraged to view the `div` element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable. Use of more appropriate elements instead of the `div` element leads to better accessibility for readers and easier maintainability for authors.

Answer (score 14):

With HTML5, besides using the [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes) which can be used on any element, you can also define your own attributes using the [`data-` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

```
<div class="marvellous" data-for="xy" data-another-attribute="nothing"></div>
```

[John Resig on `data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

All you have to do is use the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) and your page will be valid. This doctype works fine even in older browsers.

Comment: "You can use any attribute if you give them the data- prefix:": This is a misleading oversimplification, certainly not worth bumping this thread. `data-` attributes are not synonyms for other attributes, they are generic and mean nothing on their own.

Comment: @Madmartigan You are right about that. Deleted the misleading sentence. I added this information because the answers to this question are a bit outdated.

Answer (score 5):

A list of attributes is available here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

- class
- dir
- id
- lang
- style
- title
- xml:lang

Plus all the event attributes:

- onclick
- ondblclick
- onmousedown
- onmousemove
- onmouseout
- onmouseover
- onmouseup
- onkeydown
- onkeypress
- onkeyup

Answer (score 3):

contenteditable attribute also helpful and rarely used.

```
<div contenteditable="true">Using this on runtime content can changed.</div>
```

This attribute is provide a way to use this like a Normal textbox. but text changed on browser side is not saved in coding.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3nrhv7w3/1/)