# Why is JQuery not passing the post_id and post_type from replacement div

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, django-views

I fixed the like/unlike functions and now they work, but if you click "Unlike" after clicking "Like" (or visa versa) without reloading the page, the post_id and post_type don't get passed to the view. I tried to pass them to the html that replaces the buttons and I can see them on the new div but that didn't get passed to the view from there either. I'm not sure what to do since I don't understand how the data is getting lost. I also put two div tags in the replacement html that hold the id and type as values because I needed a script in the replacement html (didn't know that) for the button to work. Why is the JS not able to grab the data from the replacement html?

The code is fairly long so I apologize in advance

feed.html (snippet of the main html)

```
                <div class="like-stuff">
                {% if not request.user|user_liked_post:post %}
                <button class='like-post-btn' value="{{like_btn_val}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
                Like
                </button>                
                {% else %}
                <button class='like-post-btn' value="{{like_btn_val}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
                Unlike
                </button>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="like-count">{{post.like_count}}<div>

                {% if not request.user|user_disliked_post:post %}
                <button class='dislike-post-btn' value="{{dislike_btn_val}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
                Dislike
                </button>
                {% else %}
                <button class='dislike-post-btn' value="{{dislike_btn_val}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
                Undislike
                </button>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="dislike-count">{{post.dislike_count}}</div>
                </div>
<script src="static/js/handle_likes.js"></script>
```

likes.html (replacement html)

```
<div id="post_id" value="{{post_id}}">id: {{post_id}}</div>
<div id="post_type" value="{{post_type}}">type: {{post_type}}</div>
<div class="like-stuff">

<button class='like-post-btn' value="{{like_btn_val}}">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
{{like_btn}}
</button>
<h1>{{like_count}}</h1>

<button class='dislike-post-btn' value="{{dislike_btn_val}}">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
{{dislike_btn}}
</button>
<h1>{{dislike_count}}</h1>
</div>
<script src="static/js/handle_likes.js"></script>
```

handle_likes.js (like and unlike functions

```
$(".like-post-btn").on('click', function(){
    console.log("Thing was clicked!"); // sanity check
    if ($(".like-post-btn").val() == "not-liked") {
        console.log($('.like-post-btn').val());
        like_post();
    }
    if ($(".like-post-btn").val() == "is-liked") {
        unlike_post();
    }

});
// Start functions to handle likes/dislikes
function like_post(){
    console.log("Like post called...") // sanity check
    console.log("Test JQuery like post..");
    console.log($("#post_id"));
    console.log($("#post_type"));
    $.ajax({
        url: "posting/liking_post/",
        data: {
            post_id : $("#post_id").val(),
            post_type : $("#post_type").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('.like-stuff').html(data);
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Please contact an admin; We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};

function unlike_post(){
    console.log("Unlike post called...") // sanity check
    console.log("Test JQuery unlike post..");
    console.log($("#post_id"));
    console.log($("#post_type"));
    $.ajax({
        url: "posting/unlike_post/",
        data: {
            post_id : $("#post_id").val(),
            post_type : $("#post_type").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.like-stuff').html(data);
            },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! Please contact an admin for we have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def like_post(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
        post_type = request.GET.get('post_type')
        print("Debug in like_post line 452:",post_id, post_type)
        if not post_id or not post_type:
            raise Exception("Post id or Post type not passed to 'like post' please fix it")
        post = toolz.get_post(post_id, post_type)
        if not user_liked(request.user, post):
            like = Like(
                user=request.user,
                content_object=post
            )
            like.save()
            like_count = post.like_count + 1
            post.like_count = like_count
            print("Like count:", post.like_count)
            post.save()
            # Start data declarations
            like_count = post.like_count
            print(like_count)
            dislike_btn = "Dislike"
            dislike_btn_val = "not-disliked"
            dislike_count = post.dislike_count
            data = {
            'post_id': post_id,
            'post_type': post_type,
            'like_count': like_count,
            'like_btn': 'Unlike',
            'like_btn_val': 'is-liked',
            'dislike_btn':dislike_btn,
            'dislike_btn_val': dislike_btn_val,
            'dislike_count': dislike_count
            }
            return render(None, 'likes.html', data)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("You're trying to like the post twice...stop it")
    else:
        raise Exception("Not ajax")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div's do not have a value attribute (as [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185519/what-are-valid-attributes-for-the-div-element-in-html)), but if you have to use value in div you can use .attr('value').

```
$('#post_id').attr('value')
$('#post_type').attr('value')
```

Comment: Do you know a better way to pass information to ajax? I feel like passing all of this through the DOM is going to make everything so cluttered. I just changed the div to a hidden button with no type lol. Now it will like, then unlike but if you try to click like again to like it again (just testing because people do that kind of stuff) it doesn't work. Do you know why that happens? Also is there a better way to do this? because this feels horribly jenky.

Comment: Try to keep it simple. Try to remove duplicate code.
You use two methods for ajax but the difference is only in url of action.
If i have to do i will make it with one method. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_like_dislike). I will use only one button and if it's already liked will show it with some class(different color) and replace only count. About the testing "if you try to click like again to like it again" check events in browser console -i think there is a problem with binding of event after replacing from response, but it is only guess.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I've been battling with this for a good week now because I haven't been able to find a good tutorial on ajax with django. No one explains where the data comes from, how to access it, how to set up the template for replacing, nor what kind of request method is used when you're not using user input to change the db but still need to make changes. Obviously I figured it out but still, this has been horrifying. Thank you again, I'll change up the functions, I'm just not sure how to change only the url in the ajax

Comment: You're right, somehow the event gets unbound from the element. Here goes another week lol