# How to change the strike-out / line-through thickness in CSS?

Tags: html, css, strikethrough

I'm using the `text-decoration: line-through` in CSS, but I can't seem to find any way to vary the line thickness without inelegant hacks like `<hr>` or image overlays.

Is there any elegant way to specify the thickness of a line-through?

Comment: You can check [transparent strikethrought on text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082524/css-text-with-transparent-strikethrought) for a transparent strike through effect on text.

Answer (score 126):

The modern solution is to use the [text-decoration-thickness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness) property.

```
text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
```

You can also change the color using the [text-decoration-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color) property.

```
text-decoration-color: #ff0000aa;
```

For older browsers, you can use one of these workarounds:

Here's a pure CSS method that doesn't require any unnecessary wrapper elements. As an added bonus, not only can you adjust the thickness of the strikeout, but you can control its color separately from the text color:

```css
.strikeout {
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.strikeout::after {
  border-bottom: 0.125em solid red;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  margin-top: calc(0.125em / 2 * -1);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span class="strikeout">Struck out text</span>
```

Use RGBa colors to make the strikeout semi-transparent:

```css
.strikeout {
  font-size: 4em;
  position: relative;
}
.strikeout::after {
  border-bottom: 0.125em solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-top: calc(0.125em / 2 * -1);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span class="strikeout">Struck out text</span>
```

Or even make the strikeout a gradient! Just use a `background` combined with a `height`, in place of a `border`:

```css
.strikeout {
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.strikeout::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 255, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  content: "";
  height: 0.125em;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: calc(0.125em / 2 * -1);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span class="strikeout">Struck out text</span>
```

This works in IE9 (sans gradient) and up – or even IE8 if you use the single-colon `:after` syntax and manually write the negative `margin-top` value instead of using `calc()`.

The main downside is that this only works on a single line of text. But hey, you take what you can get ;-)

Comment: Nice! But any ways to make it works on multiple lines? Thanks!

Comment: @user2335065: Hmm...wrap each line of text in a `div`, then use `.strikeout div::after`? Of course, that won't work if the text (and/or the width of the lines) is dynamic...

Comment: This solution works perfectly on a single line of text

Comment: For IE8, what value do I put for margin-top if I'm not using calc()?

Comment: Worked for my case, but, I needed to drop the font-size: 4em;  line-height: 1em;.

Comment: Is this solution independent of how the font-size of the text is set? 
Unfortunately `text-decoration-thickness` is not working for my needs, so I need to find a workaround to have a line-through line in my text.

Answer (score 29):

This seems to be a longstanding question without an ideal solution for multi-line strikethroughs.

Conveniently, using CSS gradients, you can easily adjust your line thickness like so:

```
strike {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 7px,#cc1f1f 7px,#cc1f1f 9px,transparent 9px);
}
```

See the demo and full vendor prefixing here: http://codepen.io/pearlchen/pen/dhpxu

Comment: Nice trick, but this is better written with relative units instead. Something like `background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 45%, #cc1f1f 45% 55%, transparent 55%);` (units are relative to element height by default).

Comment: great solution.

Comment: Shows underneath the text for del elements

Answer (score 9):

short answer: no. it depends on the font, it's the same for the thickness of underline—it changes with the thickness of the text

Answer (score 5):

This is super easy these days, Use the following CSS

```
text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
```

You can adjust the thickness according to your needs.

Can change the color like this

```
text-decoration-color: red;
```

Supported by main browsers

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea but it would require adding an additional element for each level of thickness.

html

```
<span><strike>test test</strike></span><br />  
<span id="test"><strike>           </strike></span>
```

css

```
span {height:1em}
#test {position:relative;top:-1.3em}
```

BTW the spaces in the second span are specials - you will have to use alt+0160 or alt+255.
You can use pixels unit too on the negative top when ull try to position it precisely.

---

There is another alternative which involve using first *text-decoration* and then style `<strike>` or `<del>` and see if you can nudge it vertically without moving the text with it.

html

```
<span><strike>test test</strike></span>
```

css

```
span {text-decoration:line-through;color:red}
strike {position:relative;top:1px}
```

Both are working fine here, but remember to use a transitional doctype cause `<strike>` has been deprecated.

Comment: Instead of using `strike` use `text-decoration: line-through`.

Comment: Yes, I read it. I understand your solution with two levels of elements. But you should change the inner `strike` to be another `span` with css. Is there some reason you *must* use `strike`?

Comment: @ariel if you use 2 spans you will have to use classes or IDs to match them. It's just more convenient.

Comment: You can use the css child selector. `span>span { .. }`

Comment: @ariel that depends on the browsers targeted…

Comment: Meaning all browsers since IE6? No one targets IE6 anymore, and everything else supports it. (I double checked before recommending this method.)

Comment: @ariel true but I answered in 2010 :)

Comment: touché :) But maybe you should update the answer, since people today still want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I've found another approach for multiline text:

```
span {
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAADCAIAAADdv/LVAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAASSURBVHjaYvrPwMDEAMEAAQYACzEBBlU9CW8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center; 
}
```

http://output.jsbin.com/weqovenopi/1/

This approach assumes repeating an image (1px width and npx height). Also it works independent on the font-size.

Only one disadvantage - background renders under the text.

Answer (score 1):

No.

However, if the strike-through color is the same as the text color, you can easily get away with using a custom image in the background.

If you require different colors, then overlaying the custom strike-through image is the only way to go.

Comment: I found that this works for different colours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text

The only obstacle is thickness. I can't find any easy solutions either... maybe this is not worth pursuing.

Answer (score 1):

The line thickness is determined by the font (family, size, etc.).  There is no provision in CSS for changing this http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#text-decoration

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but there is a way to do it using nested span tags:

```
<span style="text-decoration: line-through; font-size: 2em;">
  <span style="font-size: 0.5em; vertical-align: middle;">
    Striked Text
  </span>
</span>
```

Strikethrough is dependent upon the size of the font, so if you double the outer span it will make the line twice as thick.  Then, you need to reduce the inner one by half.  The vertical-align is  necessary or else the line is too high, making it appear to almost be an overline.

In action:  http://jsfiddle.net/moodleboy/deep3qw8/

Works in <strike>Chrome</strike>/FF, but not Safari, IE10 or Opera.  Works on Chrome on Mac, but not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question, but is relevant in that it solves the lack of a unique strike-through using scripting. I am not a purist, but I believe this is a x-browser solution.

```
<html>
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function do_strike_out(idx)
{
  $(this).wrap("<span style='position:relative;left:0px;top:0px;'>").
    before( "<span style='margin-top:10px;border-top:1px solid #FF0000;"+
      "position:absolute;width:100%;left:0px;'></span>" ).
    wrap("<span style='position:relative;left:0px;top:0px;'>");
}
$(function(){
  $('.strike_out').each(do_strike_out);
});
</script>
<body>
A jquery hack to do colored strike-through <span class='strike_out'>STRIKE-OUT</span>, which, I realize does not answer your question, sorry, but may be of intest for others.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find an appropriate method here so I used
background-image with a [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) and [**ex** CSS length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Units).

Unfortunately this means that using different font faces will render the strikethrough in a slightly different position (if the fonts have different x-heights for example).

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.multiline-strikethrough {
  display: inline;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 1.1ex, red 1.1ex, red 1.3ex, transparent 1.3ex);
}

.alt-1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.alt-2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="multiline-strikethrough">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisis, odio a consequat eleifend, leo ex tincidunt magna.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="multiline-strikethrough alt-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisis, odio a consequat eleifend, leo ex tincidunt magna.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="multiline-strikethrough alt-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla facilisis, odio a consequat eleifend, leo ex tincidunt magna.</p>
</div>
```