# transparent strikethrought on text

Tags: css, svg, fonts, css-shapes

I need to implement a **transparent strikethrought on text with CSS** so I don't have to replace the `<h1>` tag by an `<img>` tag. I have managed to implement a line-through on the text with CSS but I can't make it transparent.

The desired effect :

[image: Text with a transprent strikethrought line]

What I have :

```css
body{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
h1{
    font-family:arial;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
h1:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    left:0; top:17px;
    background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>EXAMPLE</h1>
```

How I can I implement the **transparent strikethrought which extrudes my text** and allows the background to appear in this line.

Comment: that is an image, most likely created with illustrator, where a clipping mask was used to "cut out" that line through the text allowing you to see the background behind it. Cannot be done in html and css

Comment: @ChrisM even thought the "cut out" effect isn't often achievable with CSS, this one is.

Comment: @web-tiki OK, I guess technically, you've accomplished it with a bit of a hack.  You're actually writing the word twice and cutting off parts.  I don't understand why `line-height:0` pushes the text up showing the bottom half instead of the top though.

Comment: @ChrisM well it all depends on what you consider as a hack. The CSS/HTML is valid according to W3 standards in my implementation. For the text showing only the bottom part, it is because of `line-height:0`, it verticaly centers the text to the top of the container and as I set `overlow:hidden` on the container, only the bottom part of the text appears.

Comment: aha!  I will have to play around with `line-height`.  it's not a rule I've utilized very often.  I would think `line-height:0` would make it disappear completely. obviously that is not the case

Comment: @ChrisM it doesn't hide it completly becasue I set the height of the element. The `overflow:hidden;` property hides according to the height, not according to the line-height.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may achieve the **transparent strikethrought on text** only with CSS with the use of `line-height` and `overflow:hidden;` properties.

Demo : **[CSS transparent strike through](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/YXwyRa)**

Output :

[image: Text with a transparent cut out strikethrough with CSS]

---

**Explanation :**

1. *Step 1 :* hide the bottom of the `<h1>`text with
   `height:0.52em; overflow:hidden;`  use em units so that the height adapts to the font size you are using for the `<h1>` tag 
   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QFJJ7/4/)
2. *Step 2 :* "rewrite" the content in a pseudo element to minimise markup and prevent content repetition. You may use a custom data attribute in order to keep all the content in the markup and don't have to edit the CSS for every title.
   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QFJJ7/5/)
3. *step 3 :* align the pseudo element text to the top so only the bottom is shown with `line-height:0;` 
   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QFJJ7/)

---

**Relevant code :**

```css
body{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
h1{
    font-family:arial;
    position:relative;
}
h1 span, h1:after{
    display:inline-block;
    height:0.52em;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:5em;
}

h1:after{
    content: attr(data-content);   
    line-height:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%; left:0;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-content="EXAMPLE" ><span>EXAMPLE</span></h1>
```

---

### SVG

Another approach for this effect is to use SVG with a [mask element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking#Masking). The [demo](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/YXwyRa) shows that approach and here is the relevant code :

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body{height:100%;}
body{background: url(https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7140/13689149895_0cce1e2292_o.jpg) center bottom; background-size:cover;text-align:center;}
svg{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:darkorange;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  margin-top:5vh;
  width:85%;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 13">
  <defs>
    <mask id="strike">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="13" fill="#fff" />
      <rect x="0" y="5" width="100" height="1" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <text id="text1" x="50" y="8.5" font-size="7" text-anchor="middle" fill="darkorange" mask="url(#strike)">SVG strike through</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: What a clever implementation.

Comment: Thanks you, I try to implement this but I'll try to use ´:before´and ´:after´to the text can be highlight yet with transparent color. I'll post this if I success.

Comment: @Kael sorry but I don't understand your last comment :(

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in webkit browsers using masking

CSS

```
h1 {
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, white 20px, transparent 20px,  transparent 24px, white 24px);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DG3F4/)

[hover demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DG3F4/1/)