# Change strike-through text color in css

Tags: html, css

My html is:

```
<html>  
<body>  
     <div id="example">this is example</div>  
</body>  
<html>
```

My css is:

```
#example{text-decoration: line-through;color:#ccc;}
```

**I am getting out-put like this**
 [image: out-put image] 
 **but I want like this**
 [image: i am trying to do like this]  but I can't. Help me to do like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Color applies to the line through and text. You need to nest like.

```
<span style="text-decoration: line-through; color: red;">
 <span style="color: #CCC;">text with red linethrough and black text</span>
</span>
```

Source: http://www.savio.no/artikler/a/335/different-font-color-than-line-through-color-with-css

Comment: It would be good if you give link to original answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1107556/293712

Comment: Then this link reference would have helped. Its good habit to give credit to source.

Comment: No hard feelings. Its not only about credit. In this case, the reference is a very good article which  not only says how to do it, but also the drawbacks etc. which will be of great help.

Comment: strike or del html tags look cleaner:
<del>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#999">facebook</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</del>

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, it works correctly.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="example">
    this is example
    <span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#example{
    color:#ccc;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#example span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/RHPHX/1/

Comment: doesnt work when there's more than one line though