# strikethrough for text in the drop down list

Tags: html, css

I want to use strike throught for the text in drop down list. Is it possible through CSS or JavaScript ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS for drop down list: `text-decoration:line-through`

Comment: Oops, I stopped worrying about IE a long time ago. Is there an alternative then that works for all?

Comment: I works for all the drop down list elements. It works for only one element. BUT ===> It does not work for only word. EX: If drop down list has one item "my name is xyz" and I want to use strike through for only "name". It does not work.

Comment: @user583726 Even though you can apply style to the individual option element the value displayed on the select will always be a plain text value. In fact Firefox it will only read the first text node, so you can't even use XHTML or DOM manipulation to work around it.

Comment: @Abhranil Das: do you know if it's possible as per my comment ?

Comment: @user583726: the CSS works for whichever element you apply it to. If you want only one word to be strikethrough, put that word in a span, and give it a class. Then instead of applying the strikethrough to the dropdown list element, apply it to that span class.

Comment: WARNING : Don't work IN IE & SAFARI. so IT DOES NOT WORK FOR WEB.

Answer (score 0):

Dup: [CSS strikethrough different color from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text)
 This link not only has what you are looking for, but also shows how to make the line a different color. Your just gonna have to find the CSS that your drop down list text is using.

Comment: I works for all the drop down list elements. It works for only one element. BUT ===> It does not work for only word. EX: If drop down list has one item "my name is xyz" and I want to use strike through for only "name". It does not work

Comment: :any idea if it is possible any how ?

Comment: yeah. You would have to tag name as a different class and not modify the <li> tag.
Something like this
#Your CSS
li.strike{
text-decoration:line-through;
}
#Your HTML
<li>My <div class="strike">Name</div>is xyz