# Making a white strikethrough in css for other browsers

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a white strike through in my active nav. It works in firefox but for the other browsers it only shows up in black. Is there a way to get it to be white.

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills menu">
        <li class="nav_item">
            <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
            <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/index.php?section=2">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
            <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/index.php?section=3">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/index.php?section=4">CONTACT US</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.active {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddel: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/evnc1cea/3/)

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: Can you give us some code? of perhaps a jsfiddle?

Comment: <span style='color:white;text-decoration:line-through'>
 <p>your text here</p>
</span>

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS strikethrough different color from text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Chrome:

```
.active a{
    text-decoration-color: inherit;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.active {
    color:#fff;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/evnc1cea/5/)**

Comment: That kind of worked, but not it's not working in firefox or safari

Answer (score 0):

Try this setting it to the `a`

```
.active a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/evnc1cea/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills menu">
            <li class="nav_item">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/" style="color:white;text-decoration:line-through"><span style='color:black;'>HOME</span></a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav_item">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/index.php?section=2" style="color:white;text-decoration:line-through"><span style='color:black;'>ABOUT US</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav_item">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/index.php?section=3" style="color:white;text-decoration:line-through"><span style='color:black;'>PORTFOLIO</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/index.php?section=4" style="color:white;text-decoration:line-through"><span style='color:black;'>CONTACT US</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```