# Overline with color different from text in Qt

Tags: css, qt

I am making a Qt application, where I need to have a text in QTextEdit overlined but the overline should have other color than the text. I tried to do it using CSS like this: [CSS strikethrough different color from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text/1107556#1107556) But it  doesn't work in Qt. Code:

```
ui->textEdit_2->setText("<span style=\"color:blue;text-decoration:overline\"><span style=\"color:red\">text</span></span>");
```

Comment: Show ur code then?

Comment: Ok, here it is.