# How to add color to a line-through click event within react?(without it changing the font color too)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styling

All I'm trying to do here, is make it so that the line-through click event turns red upon clicking on it, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere on how to do this. I tried a few things and nothing has worked. 
Edit: I added "color":"red" after "none" and now the line is red, but it also turned my font color red.

```
    <ul
    style={{
      textDecoration: this.props.completed ? "line-through" : "none"
    }}
    onClick={this.handleClick}
    >
    {this.props.task}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS strikethrough different color from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text)

Comment: For future reference, if you have a problem like this you would google something like 'css change color of line-through' and then look through the StackOverflow links.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for `'the right react syntax for multiple conditional styling'`.

Styling requires object then you can try sth like:

```
<ul
  style={{
    textDecoration: this.props.completed ? "line-through" : "none",
    color: this.props.completed ? "red" : "black"
  }}
  onClick={this.handleClick}
>
{this.props.task}
</ul>
```

You should read [this docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) - better solution is to define css class 'task-completed' (red, line-through, italic, whatever) and assign this class conditionally. It can be done (by className) as in docs or a few other ways, f.e.

```
<ul className={`task-item ${this.props.completed ? " task-completed" : ""}`}
      onClick={this.handleClick}
>
  {this.props.task}
</ul>
```

or without ternary operator

```
className={`task-item ${this.props.completed && "task-completed"}`}
```

For more complex dependencies you can use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)