# Strikethrough a Paragraph in React.js via onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strikethrough

I'm pretty much ready to rip my hair out. So my final project in my Javascript class is an experimental thing with learning React.js, where you do a basic todo list. I got all that done and working, and I can have it add things properly. But my final hurdle is making it so that onclicking the printed paragraph from the button will cause them to give the printed paragraphs the strikethrough property, which can be undone by clicking on it again.

I've looked up everywhere, I've tried other examples from here, and ***nothing*** I can think of gets the strikethrough to take place. I tried a basic Javascript function that would do what I wanted if this was an HTML/non-react file, but it breaks the react page when I try to plop it in. So I spent a stupidly long time on a tutorial trying to figure out what to do, and I maybe figured out the step in the right direction? But I still can't get anything to happen and I don't know how to establish an onclick to this.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    setCurrentToDoItem = (toDoItem) => {
        console.log("toDoItem", toDoItem);

        this.setState({
            currentToDoItem: toDoItem
        });
    };

    saveToDoListItem = (toDoItem) => {
        this.setState({
            toDoList: [...this.state.toDoList,
                toDoItem]


        });

    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentToDoItem: null,
            toDoList: [],
            strikeThrough: []
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <h1>To Do List</h1>
                <label>To Do Item: </label>
                <input
                    onChange={(event) => this.setCurrentToDoItem(event.target.value)}>
                </input>
                <button onClick={() => this.saveToDoListItem(this.state.currentToDoItem)}>
                    <p>Add Item</p>
                </button>
                <p>{this.state.currentToDoItem}</p>


                <div>
                    <p>To Do Items</p>
                    {
                        this.state.toDoList.map((item, index) => <p key={index}>{item} </p>)
                    }
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

This is my App.js code. As you can see, everything else should work fine, but I have no clue how to add a strikethrough effect to what would result from the `this.state.toDoList.map((item, index) => <p key={index}>{item} </p>)` bit like I would with a function in normal javascript. How do I make the printed lines strikethrough via onclick, and then how do I undo that by clicking on it again? (I assume with a second onclick) I really just need to know how to get a working strikethrough with this, as everything else is pretty much working.

Comment: Have you tried CSS? On click, add a class say `task-done` and inside it, you can use css to do the job. For [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text)

Comment: @Rajesh I did try a javascript function with CSS, assuming it would work, so my CSS I tried with was like so:
```
(function() {
document
 .getElementById("list")
 .addEventListener("click", function(e) { e.originalTarget.classList.toggle("line"); });
})();
```
And i would then add the "line" class to the css file that assigns anything with that class with a linethrough text decoration, and give the list value to another part of that P tag, but I can't seem to get the function to work on the page without it exploding.

Comment: Alrighty, I experimented by adding a CSS named endTask, and made it strikethrough. I assume I have to find a way to get it to onclick with the now-new "strike" paragraph ID tag I just added onto the <p id = "strike" key={index}>{item} </p> line. So I need to find a way to have clicking anything with the strike ID cause it to get added to the endTask CSS and get striked... That's the roadblock

Comment: @CollegeFox: do you just want to strikethrough, or need any effects while strikethrough?

Comment: Add a new array where you can store all the done tasks and save it to state. Then for each tasks, add a ternary condition if it meets the condition (which is, this task is in the array of "tasks done" then add this style textDecoration: "line-through";

Comment: To check if its in the array, you can use find function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most comfortable ways to do that is as advised in comments. A really quick way to implement this is to toggle class list. In the code bellow, I added a function `crossLine` which toggles class name "crossed-line" and adds event listener on mapped to-dos (in `render` function). Then in your `App.css` add a line

```css
.crossed-line {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Here's your edited component code.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentToDoItem: null,
            toDoList: [],
            strikeThrough: []
        };
    }
    setCurrentToDoItem = toDoItem => {
        this.setState({
            currentToDoItem: toDoItem
        });
    };

    saveToDoListItem = toDoItem => {
        this.setState({
            toDoList: [...this.state.toDoList, toDoItem]
        });
    };

    crossLine = event => {
        const element = event.target;
        element.classList.toggle("crossed-line");
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>To Do List</h1>
                <label>To Do Item: </label>
                <input
                    onChange={event =>
                        this.setCurrentToDoItem(event.target.value)
                    }
                />
                <button
                    onClick={() =>
                        this.saveToDoListItem(this.state.currentToDoItem)
                    }
                >
                    <p>Add Item</p>
                </button>
                <p>{this.state.currentToDoItem}</p>

                <div>
                    <p>To Do Items</p>
                    {this.state.toDoList.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <p onClick={this.crossLine} key={index}>
                                {item}{" "}
                            </p>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the ultimate lifesaver for me. It shows me how it's done while also letting me know how to back-work from it for future projects. (if I end up getting another thing in this field again) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As commented, you will have to keep a handle click and add class to add strikethrough using CSS.

For this I have updated your JSX to:

```
<p onClick={ () => this.handleClick(index) } className={ item.isComplete ? 'completed' : '' } key={index}>{item.value} </p>
```

and the signature of `toDoItem` from string to an object:

```
{
    value: string;
    isComplete: boolean
}
```

and based on this flag, I'm adding class.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentToDoItem: null,
      toDoList: [],
      strikeThrough: []
    };

    this.setCurrentToDoItem = this.setCurrentToDoItem.bind(this);
    this.saveToDoListItem = this.saveToDoListItem.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  setCurrentToDoItem(toDoItem) {
    this.setState({
      currentToDoItem: toDoItem
    });
  }

  saveToDoListItem(toDoItem) {
    this.setState({
      toDoList: [...this.state.toDoList, {
        value: toDoItem,
        isComplete: false
      }]
    });
  }

  handleClick(index) {
    const {
      toDoList
    } = this.state;
    toDoList[index].isComplete = !toDoList[index].isComplete;
    this.setState({
      toDoList
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>To Do List</h1>
          <label>To Do Item: </label>
          <input
              onChange={(event) => this.setCurrentToDoItem(event.target.value)}>
          </input>
          <button onClick={() => this.saveToDoListItem(this.state.currentToDoItem)}>
              <p>Add Item</p>
          </button>
          <p>{this.state.currentToDoItem}</p>
          <div>
              <p>To Do Items</p>
              {
                this.state.toDoList.map((item, index) =>
                  <p onClick={ () => this.handleClick(index) } className={ item.isComplete ? 'completed' : '' } key={index}>{item.value} </p>)
              }
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-kare-go2vf

I have modified your code to achieve the required functionality.
This code does exactly what you want.

Comment: Just a minor comment, look at **[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Examples)** api and use `.toggle` function. However, playing with DOM elements is kinda wrong

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion:). But, I think manipulating elements just for styling purposes doesn't have any downsides.

Comment: I would disagree. Changing DOM element directly will make virtual dom dirty as it would not be same as DOM. The whole objective of using a UI library is to handle UI interactions in a predefined way. If you use, DOM manipulation, it beats the purpose of using it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

### Update : Created a [TODO fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/nirus/auLsmycz/) code using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) for modern code approach.

```
const initialState = {
  items: [
    { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
    { text: "Learn React", done: false },
    { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
    { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
  ]
};

function appReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ITEM_STATUS_CHANGE':{
       let affected = state.items.slice();
       affected[action.index].done = !affected[action.index].done;
       return Object.assign({}, state,  { items: affected });
    }

    case 'ADD_ITEM_TO_LIST':{
       let affected = state.items.slice();
       affected.push({ text: action.data, done : false})   
       return Object.assign({}, state,  { items: affected });
    }

    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function TodoApp(props){
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(appReducer, initialState);

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos: 
          <input type="text" id="todoTextItem"/>
          <button 
          onClick={()=>{
                dispatch({
                type: 'ADD_ITEM_TO_LIST',
                data: window.todoTextItem.value
              })
          }}
          >Add Item</button>
        </h2>
        <ol>
        {state.items.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <label>
              <input 
                type="checkbox"
                checked={item.done}
                onChange={()=>{
                    dispatch({
                    type: 'ITEM_STATUS_CHANGE',
                    index: index,
                  })
                }}
              /> 
              <span className={item.done ? "done" : ""}>{item.text}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        ))}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

and in CSS

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**Explanation:**

Basically i am creating a list with done boolean flag which is `false` by default, which helps to identify if the TODO items added to the list is finished or not using [`reducers`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). With that logic class `.done` is toggled. *You can change the code according to your need by segregating TODO list from done list items while setting state*

> This is a Unit testable code by creating Jest snapshot. Never to manipulate DOM directly, which will defeat the purpose of React's snapshot testing.

---

#### Old [fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/nirus/89y5Lofb/) using **Class Component**.

*Use this to compare and learn modern hooks concepts from class based.*