# Line-through in different color as of text in emails

Tags: html, css, html-email

[image]

I am trying to make the `text-decoration: line-through;` color red and the text color should be black or any other color in email. Have tried adding a span wrapper and then setting its color to red. Used strike tag, s tag. Used inline css

```html
<span class="strike" style=" color: #444 !important; text-decoration: line-through; text-decoration-color: #ff0000; "><span class="textMsg">strike with different color</span></span>
<br />
<span class="textMsg" style=" color: #444 !important; text-decoration: line-through; text-decoration-color: #ff0000; ">strike with different color</span>
<br />
<span style="color: black;position: relative;"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x1/ff0000/fff" style=" position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); left: 0; width: 100%; ">strike with different color</span>
```

Comment: Is there an issue?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?    Do you try to make it as underline ? Like using `border-bottom: 1px solid red;` ? Please describe clearly your problem

Comment: `text-decoration-color` is a new property and is unlikely to be supported by most email clients. - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS strikethrough different color from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text)

Comment: i am trying to make line-through different as that of text. For example my text color should be in black and the strike color to be in red but in email not on web page. its basically a actual price and a discount price.. i have also attached image

Answer (score 1):

`text-decoration-color` is the way to go, but it’s not supported in every email clients: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-text-decoration-color/